# how to get it to work this rewrite rule for replacing and redirecting at the same time?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I believed to understand rewrite rules

when I coded my first website I also provided its root with a .htacces file to manage a simple scenario:
"when a URI doesn't represent an existing directory or file, run article.php but keep the URI for the audience"

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ article.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

And it worked fine!

Now, I would like to enhance this rule do deal with a slightly complex scenario:
"when a URI doesn't represent an existing directory or file, replace its hypotetical slashes (even a trail slash) with dashes; then, run article.php but keep the new URI for the audience"

I've checked Apache rewrite documentation (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html) and followed the next reasoning:

1. there can be characters before and after the slash ^( )/( )$
2. in whatever amount ^( +)/( +)$
3. except the slash itself ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$
4. there may be a trailing slash ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$
5. finally, the substitution will have the two groups of characters with a dash between them $1-$2

To sum up, the new RewriteRule sould be:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ article.php/$1-$2 [NC,L]
```

But it doesn't work. I'm getting 404 object not found ;-(
I'm pretty sure that the trouble is not about formalism. I've worked with the glance on Apache documentation. At this point there must be something I've misunderstood conceptually. Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: where url you tried get 404?

Comment: I tried http://localhost/alfa/beta/gamma/ and I expected to get http://localhost/alfa-beta-gamma- while running article.php but I'm rather getting http://localhost/alfa/beta/gamma/ and no article.php

Comment: because `alfa/beta/gamma` not matches the regex `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$`